# How to do picture in picture with Premier Pro Multicamera

Tags: premiere, multi-camera

I LOVE the multicamera magic in Premier Pro CC but I can't quite figure out how to do a picture in picture shot like at the start of this video:

The multi camera sequence allows switching between different cameras but I can't figure out how to have more than one camera visible at a time? Is this possible? So far I have just dragged 2 of the multi-camera sequences onto the stage but then I need to synchronize those. That seems silly when they are already synchronized.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't select, say, two video tracks from your Multi-cam sequence and show them at the same time. You're going to have to go at it separately. A Multi-Cam sequence is really for going back and forth between angles, not to show two or more angles at the same time.

A solution:
- On Video track 1, put your base image or shot.
- One Video track 2, put the image or film you'd like to have appear over the base image. Sync the two video tracks together, by hand. That is, don't create a Multi-Cam sequence: merely put them one on top of the other so that they start at the same time of the take. 
- Then, use the "Crop" effect and the "Scale" tool to reduce the size of your Track2 image and move it in the appropriate corner of your base image.

Voila! You have two angles of the same event playing at the same time in the same overall image.